# Using New York Times API with no returns

Tags: python, json, newsletter, no-response

I have tried to fetch news articles from New York Times but there were no return. No response at all. I troubleshooted and tested the URL on web browser, it does return the news articles. And on the NYT developer's 'PATHS' page, it also returned 200 for my API. I wonder if it's because the news articles I want from the past two months are too large, and the sleep time is not enough to limit the API rate? Can someone please help me with my code?

```
api_key = "my_NYT_api_key"
query = "Israel Palestine"
filter_query = "news_desk:(\"Foreign\"OR \"Politics\" OR \"World\") AND type_of_material:(\"News\" OR \"Article\") AND pub_date:([2023-10-07 TO 2023-11-21]) "
page = "0"
sort = "relevance"
facet_fields = "news_desk,section_name"
def send_request(query, filter_query, facet_fields, api_key):
   base_url = "https://api.nytimes.com/svc/search/v2/articlesearch.json"
   url = (f"{base_url}?q={query}&fq={filter_query}&facet_fields=facet_fields}&page={page}&sort={sort}&"
          f"facet=true&facet_filter=true&api-key={api_key}")
   headers = {
       'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/119.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
       'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8'
   }
   response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
   print("HTTP Status Code:", response.status_code)  # Check HTTP status
   print("Raw Response:", response.text)  # Print raw response text
   time.sleep(6)
   return response.json()


def parse_response(response):
   data = {
       'headline': [],
       'pub_date': [],
       'web_url': [],
       'image_url': [],
       'timestamp': [],
   }

   articles = response['response']['docs']
   for article in articles:
       data['headline'].append(article['headline']['main'])
       data['pub_date'].append(article['pub_date'])
       data['web_url'].append(article['web_url'])
       data['timestamp'].append(article['pub_date'])

       multimedia = article.get('multimedia', [])
       image_url = multimedia[0]['url'] if multimedia else 'No image'
       data['image_url'].append(image_url)

   return pd.DataFrame(data)
def get_data(query, filter_query, facet_fields, api_key):
   response = send_request(query, filter_query, facet_fields, api_key)
   if response:  # Check if response is not empty
       df = parse_response(response)
       print(f"Number of articles collected: {len(df)}")
       return df
   else:
       print("No data received")
       return pd.DataFrame()
```

I wonder if it is because I have requested too many times in a day (although never returned any articles)? That is why NYT is limiting the rate from my api key?

Comment: Instead of manually building the parameters, review [Passing Parameters in URLs](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls)

Comment: I was able to successfully get the articles back using your code above. Are you sure you are using the correct api key?

Comment: I just modified my code, HTTP Status Code: 200, but the number of articles returned is 0. previously, when i put this in my browser, https://api.nytimes.com/svc/search/v2/articlesearch.json?q=Israel+Palestine&fq=news_desk:(%22Foreign%22%20OR%20%22Politics%22%20OR%20%22World%22)&facet_fields=news_desk,section_name&facet=true&facet_filter=true&api-key=X0I2ZbyKGbSftRE7f9HYoaxuItBuUc4x, it does return a bunch of articles. so i dont think it's filter problem?

Comment: Wow really! my api key should be correct, because it returns 200 in the developer's testing page and the articles returned on my web browser too, just not in my python environment..

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community My question is that if my code seems to be right and work on someone else's API key, why does it not generate ANY articles from 3 of my NYT api keys and on both Jupyter notebook and Pycharm? Am I missing something here? As I also authorized the key for article search as well.

Comment: Have you checked the response object during debugging? Does it give any hint about what's wrong with the api call?

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem. In the FAQ of NYTs API you find this:

11. Is there an API call limit?
    Yes, there are two rate limits per API: 500 requests per day and 5 requests per minute. You should sleep 12 seconds between calls to avoid hitting the per minute rate limit. If you need a higher rate limit, please contact us at code@nytimes.com.